# Convert bytes to base64 encoded string with OQL query

Tags: java, visualvm, oql

I'm using VisualVM to extract information from java heapdump. Is it possible to convert this into a base64 encoded string directly in the query?

[image]

Comment: Just to understand you question better: you have OQL query, which returns instances of `byte[]` and you want modify it to return strings representing base64 of those byte arrays. Am I right?

Comment: @TomasHurka Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OQL [map function](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html#map) and java interoperability to map byte arrays to base64 strings. The OQL below returns all `byte[]` objects:

```
select map(heap.objects('byte[]'), function (byteArr) {
  buff = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, byteArr.length);
  for (i=0; i<buff.length; i++) buff[i] = Number(byteArr[i]);
  return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buff);
})
```

For better testing you can enhance the output with the link to the actual `byte[]` instance:

```
select map(heap.objects('byte[]'), function (byteArr) {
buff = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, byteArr.length);
  for (i=0; i<buff.length; i++) buff[i] = Number(byteArr[i]);
  return toHtml(byteArr)+" "+java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buff);
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to join the whole array? The current output encodes each of them separately and not encoded correctly https://ibb.co/B4PVJZ9

Comment: You cannot use `map` this way, since it operates on array/iterator/enumeration. It needs arrays as input. Based on your image, the correct OQL should be (looks terrible, no formatting):
select map([it.decryptionCypherKey], function (byteArr) {
buff = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, byteArr.length);
  for (i=0; i<buff.length; i++) buff[i] = byteArr[i];
  return toHtml(byteArr)+" "+java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buff);
}) from org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.CookieRememberManager s

Comment: The map function worked but the byte[] is encoded to AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==, which is incorrect. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in my OQL - replace `it` with `s`. in `it.decryptionCypherKey`

Comment: That was not the cause. I fixed it before posting the question, you can take look at the original screenshot, every char is encoded to AAA before joining the array ... so the problem is from somewhere else ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256342/discussion-between-tomas-hurka-and-daisy).